# Integration of $e^{-2 k |\vec{x}|}/|\vec{x}|^2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following integral:

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \mathrm{d} \vec{x} \frac{e^{-k |\vec{x}|}}{|\vec{x}|^2} \text{ (with } k > 0\text{)}
$$

Since the integral seems to converge for the whole 3D-space I hope there is a analytic solution of it but I could not find any working idea till now. I would be very thankful if somebody of you could help me.

Comment: Maybe to be more correct I meant $\text{Re}(k) > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in spherical polar coordinates, $\mathrm{d}\vec{x} = r^2 \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi,$ we get
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \mathrm{d} \vec{x} \frac{e^{-k |\vec{x}|}}{|\vec{x}|^2}
= \int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\phi \int_0^\pi \mathrm{d}\theta \sin\theta \int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}r \, r^2 \frac{e^{-kr}}{r^2} \\
= 2\pi \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{1}{k} = \frac{4\pi}{k}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I just forgot the $r^2$ in the volume element during my attempt.